# Hive SQL Cross Join Question on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, hive, hiveql

Wonderful coders of the universe, I have a question:

I'm writing a HIVE SQL script, and I'm wondering if it's possible to cross join on a condition (condition below is where the dayofweek is a friday), or if there's a performance-light alternative to what I'm doing below.  **I ONLY need to add in 2 rows to dates that are Fridays, which is just a persist of the Friday date data for Saturdays and Sundays.  I get an error on the join condition, but I'm wondering if it's possible to bypass that somehow.**

To be crystal clear, the way the query is written below gives me an error (specifically and DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = 6).  Just wondering if there's a way to write this where the syntax will be accepted.

Please advise.

```
  select 
portfolio_name
,Cast(Date_add(a.performance_end_date, crs.crs) AS TIMESTAMP) AS performance_end_date 
,return
,nav
,nav_id
,row_no

from
(
SELECT portfolio_name, performance_end_date, return, cast(cast(nav as decimal(20,2))as string) as nav, nav_id
,row_number() over (partition by a.portfolio_code,a.performance_end_date order by a.nav_id desc) as row_no
FROM carsales a
WHERE  
portfolio_code IN ('1994','2078','2155','2365','2367')
and
year=2020 and month=09


) a
      
CROSS JOIN (SELECT stack(2, 1,2) as crs) crs     and DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = 6
           where a.row_no = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

CROSS JOIN don't have "join condition", so move your criteria to where clause

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT stack(2, 1,2) as crs) crs
           where a.row_no = 1 and DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = 6
```

Comment: If I only want the cross join to be applicable when day of week = 6 , otherwise just generate the normal amount of rows in the original table , is this not possible?  If I add it to the where clause this will only bring in Friday’s

Comment: then try some trick :
`LEFT JOIN (SELECT stack(2, 1,2) as crs, 6 as myday) crs ON DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = crs.myday
           where a.row_no = 1`